# Do operations on uniform variables get cached in GLSL?

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

Let's say I have a very simple GLSL vertex shader:

```
uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;

in vec3 position;
in vec3 color;

out vec3 vertexColor;

void main()
{
    mat4 mvp = projection * view * model;
    vertexColor = color;
    gl_Position = mvp * vec4(position, 1.0);
}
```

Is the variable `mvp` recalculated for every vertex, or is it precalculated and stored until the the uniform variables it depends on change?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could a particular implementation cache that value? Sure. Will they?

I would not assume that they would. Such caching would be difficult to implement, since it requires evaluating such expressions before draw calls, based on uniform state, then uploading those expressions to the code.

If you have some state that is computed from multiple uniform values, and you believe that such computation would be a performance problem, you are the one who should compute it.

Comment: Why would it be difficult to implement? You'd just need to create a dependency tree for the variable during the compilation and then update all variables that depend on any uniform variable that got changed.

Comment: @Bobby-Z: You say "just" as though that were trivial. It also requires that you implement an arbitrary expression calculator that can compute the value of that "dependency tree" based on the current values of the input uniforms. There's also the fact that uniforms take up shader resources, which are limited. And you would effectively be creating a fourth `mat4` uniform value. What happens if one of those manufactured uniforms is what pushes you past the uniform limits on a stage?

Comment: It is trivial to calculate the dependency tree. During compilation you find all variables referenced in the initialization expression of the `mat4`, find out if all of those variables are uniform, or if they aren't, recursively check those variables whether they only depend on uniform variables. Most modern compilers do similar things with variables.